# T-SQL: Add 1 second to subsequent fields in SQL Server 2005

Tags: t-sql, variables, sql-server-2005

I want to add 1 second to a column on every row so that each row have a unique time value.
My code works fine in SQL Server 2012, but the client has SQL Server 2005 and it fails there.

What workarounds are there?

Error on line as indicated is:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@MyVar"

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp_Times(MyTime datetime) 

INSERT INTO #Temp_Times
   SELECT GETDATE()
   FROM Tasks

DECLARE @MyVar datetime = GETDATE();
--Add 1 second to every value
UPDATE #LinkFaultAuditTrace_Temp
SET @MyVar = MyTime = DATEADD(s, 1, @MyVar);  --Here is the problem
```

Comment: "I want to add 1 second to a column on every row so that each row have a unique time value." - say, what??

Comment: while the answer below is correct, I'd question your intent....

Comment: The answer below as per marc_s comment will only work for non inline statements.  Since this is part of a query I have to find something else.  My intent is questionable yes :-)  I need to update a table in which the datetime is part of the primary key, but all the other fields are the same.  Yes, I do agree it's probably a bad DB design, but I can't change the design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried:

```
 DECLARE @MyVar datetime;
 Set @Myvar = GETDATE();
```

Comment: Right - the "inline" declare&assign at the same time is a **new feature** in SQL Server **2008** and newer and wasn't present in 2005.... sharp eyes!

Comment: Ahh, you see.  I got confused.  I thought the error was at the inline query statement.  But the error was really at the assignment.  Sorry - dumb question then.  I knew the answer all along.